# Python does not display the value of a variable in Visual Studio Code without the print function?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm learning python from a book. According to it, I should simply type the name of the variable and it should display its value in the Python Interactive window.

However, it doesn't. The simple snippet of code is:
favourite_language = "python is my favourite "
favourite_language

Why doesn't this work by printing 'python is my favourite ' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python code can either be executed through the interactive shell that you see when you type `python` in the terminal or through saving your changes in a file and executing it through `python <name of your file.py>`. This will give you different results. Running python code within the interactive shell means that you will see the REPL pattern at play: read, evaluate, print, loop.

The interactive shell will actively print the value of whatever is being executed, therefore, you can do the following:

```py
a = 2
a
# You will get 2
```

In the meantime, the Python interpreter itself (without the interactive shell) does not print a value unless explicitly specified. This behavior is generally  how you'd expect python to work in real world applications. instead, you can use the `print()` function

```py
a = 2
# a alone will still print nothing outside the shell 
print(a) # will print 2
```

You can see [this article on running Python scripts for more information](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/run-python-script-how-to-execute-python-shell-commands-in-terminal/).